# how to split column value in mongoDB and use on $gt?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Json Document is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d6ca4e90a90f7518f50946"),
    "url_Address" : "http://www.flipkart.com/fasense-women-s-nighty/p/itmdu4unkrwgtzuu?pid=NDNDU4UNKRWGTZUU&icmpid=reco_pp_same_womenclothing_nightdressnighty_3&ppid=NDNE6GKJFVF7UXUJ",
    "vendor_Name" : "Fasense",
    "vendor_rating" : "3.9 / 5",
    "product_Name" : "Fasense Women's Nighty",
    "parrent_id" : "56d6bfea2282d3e350f30808",
    "channel_name" : "flipkart",
    "MRP" : "Rs. 2,399",
    "prce" : "Rs. 1,199",

}
```

now I want to fetch `vendor_rating` and split it on `/` and then check rating is greater then 3 or not.

and the Output of the query easily can be rendered with complete documents.

How I can do this on mongoDB 2.6?

Comment: Can you help clarify your question a little bit further, are you looking to fetch documents that have the first part of the `vendor_rating` key value greater than 5 when split on the `'\'` character or you already have the documents ? What is it exactly you want to achieve here?

Comment: I want to fetch 3.9 from `vendor_rating`   and compare if it is greater then 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
db.collection.find({_id: "56d6ca4e90a90f7518f50946"}).toArray(function(err, doc){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  if(doc){
    (doc[0].vendor_rating.split('/')[0] > 3) ? console.log("Rating is > 3") : console.log("Rating is < 3");
  }
});
```

I haven't tested this yet, but it should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I edited My question .   this query should render whole document .

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I don't think what you're looking for is possible. You'll have to do the splitting   on your end.

Comment: it is giving TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Comment: @ShubhamBatra try the edited solution. That should work.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera - you can use aggregation framework to shift this process to mongo side

Answer (score 4):

so for that you will need to use aggregation framework provided by mongo.
then you don't need to process locally on client

```
    db.col.aggregate([
        {$project:{
             "_id"           :1,
             "url_Address"   :1,
             "vendor_rating" :1,
             "vendor_Name"   :1,
             "product_Name"  :1,
             "parrent_id"    :1,
             "channel_name"  :1,
             "MRP"           :1,
             "prce"          :1,
             "rating"        :{$substr:["vendor_rating",0,3]}   
        }},
        { $match: { "rating"  : {$gt : 3 }      } }
    ])
```

Comment: Will this work if the field is `"vendor_rating": "4 / 5"`?

Comment: good point! -> in this case we need to split string on "/" so - will update my answer to include that

Comment: there is  update for accepting  different values on rating field

Comment: Clever, but I'm afraid the `$size` operator in aggregation will fail for non-array type of fields.

Comment: this function don't work on string... so maybe it will be worth to store result in 3.0 / 5 form?

Comment: Or better yet store another field that is a computed value of the above, say `isRatingGreaterThanThree`. Well, that entirely depends on the OP's business logic...

Comment: @chridam - that will be perfect :-)